How to align a MAUI image with aspect-fill, within its display area?
Is there a way to align/position an <Image/> within its display area using Aspect="AspectFill" in .NET MAUI 8, or is there a workaround that produces the same visual result?
I'm trying to have a wide display area where a tall image completely fills it, maintaining its aspect ratio. The image should then be aligned to the top or bottom of its display area, so only the top or bottom of the image is visible. Input images may vary in height but the wrapping element has a fixed height, which is why I need the aspect ratio.
<Border HeightRequest="100">
    <Image 
        Source="t_pose.png"
        Aspect="AspectFill"
        WidthRequest="128"/>
</Border>

Full image :

Example desired result :

Example desired result 2 :
(image added later)


You can put your Image inside a ScrollView StackLayout. You can apply TranslationX and/or TranslationY to move the Image:
<Border HeightRequest="100">
    <StackLayout>
        <Image
            Aspect="AspectFill"
            Source="t_pose.png"
            WidthRequest="128" />
    </StackLayout>
</Border>
<Border HeightRequest="100">
    <StackLayout>
        <Image
            Aspect="AspectFill"
            Source="t_pose.png"
            TranslationY="-60"
            WidthRequest="128" />
    </StackLayout>
</Border>



This should (on paper) behave exactly the same, as the scrollview never existed. What version of MAUI makes this work? I really want to test it.

In addition, to bottom-align the image, I rotated the ScrollViews' parent element 180 degrees. Then I rotated the image back another 180 degrees. This tricks the scrollview into switching the upside and downside, thus aligning the image to the bottom. Posted my own answer as well for that. Many thanks for your answer!

@AlJohn I updated the answer adding TranslationX, TranslationY which (I think) is a better solution to the problem.

@StephenQuan You are right, thanks again. I'm implementing this version.

You need "start" aligned image, that fills the container.
What I recommend is:

Remove this from the Image. WidthRequest="128"
Place the Image inside VerticalStackLayout.
Control the width from a parent of the Image. (it can even be a grid, that holds the border, that holds the stacklayout, that holds the image.)

If you go with Quan's answer, and pick ScrollView as substitute,
you still have to remove the WidthRequest, and apply VerticalOptions="Start"
To clarify a bit why this is not ok:
The width request will work, if your aspect is covered by the height of the picture. It will correctly trim, as long as there is something to trim. The moment the height of the picture covers the border height, you will start to trim from the picture width. (You do not want to do it).
This is why the solution is start aligned, non-restricted, aspect-fill image.

In addition to Stephen Quan's answer (that I accepted), I found a bit of a dirty workaround to be able to bottom-align the image as well, to the absolute bottom of its parent.
<VerticalStackLayout Rotation="180">
    <ScrollView 
        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never"
        VerticalOptions="Start"
        HeightRequest="176"
        WidthRequest="128"
        IsEnabled="False">
        <Image 
            Source="t_pose.png"
            VerticalOptions="End"
            Aspect="AspectFill"
            WidthRequest="128"
            Rotation="180"/>
    </ScrollView>
</VerticalStackLayout>

Notice the parent element being rotated 180 degrees and the image being rotated another 180 degrees. This tricks the ScrollView into switching the up- and downside.
Not the cleanest workaround but it does the trick!
